# How to add an item to Highcharts legend?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a graph with two series: `column` and `spline`. Programatically I changed the color of some columns that met some criteria, let's say the 10 lowest scores are rendered in  green, while the rest is blue.

Now, in the legend, I have the series names, but it shows, obviously, the spline series name and the column series name in the default blue color. I want to know how to add a name to the legend for the columns that are rendered in green that says "lowest scores" for example.

EDIT:

The code for the series:

```
series: [{
  type: 'column',
  color: '#215868',
  name: 'Score per round ',
  data: [
    {y:65,name:'Caracas Country Club', color: '#7EB035'},
    {y:72,name:'Biltmore Golf Course', color: '#7EB035'},
    {y:72,name:'Nashua Country Club', color: '#7EB035'},
    {y:90,name:'Hilaman Park Golf Course'},
    {y:105,name:'Biltmore Golf Course'},
    {y:90,name:'Binks Forest Golf Club', color: '#7EB035'},
    {y:90,name:'Binks Forest Golf Club', color: '#7EB035'},
    {y:90,name:'Blackhawk Country Club | The Falls', color: '#7EB035'},
    {y:90,name:'Blackhawk Country Club | The Falls', color: '#7EB035'},
    {y:72,name:'Pembroke Country Club', color: '#7EB035'},
    {y:90,name:'The Greens At North Hills Country Club'},
    {y:90,name:'Havana Country Club | Kilamanjaro/Kenya'},
    {y:90,name:'Biltmore Golf Course'},
    {y:90,name:'Biltmore Golf Course'},
    {y:90,name:'Challenge At Santa Rita'},
    {y:100,name:'Lake Chabot Golf Course | Lake Chabot'},
    {y:90,name:'Hillcrest Golf & Country Club | Championship', color: '#7EB035'},
    {y:100,name:'Hillcrest Golf & Country Club | Championship'},
    {y:100,name:'Hillcrest Golf & Country Club | Championship'},
    {y:90,name:'Hillcrest Golf & Country Club | Championship', color: '#7EB035'},]
  },
  {
    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Avg Score',
    color: '#009900',
    data: [
      {y:89.9,name:'Caracas Country Club'},
      {y:89.4,name:'Biltmore Golf Course'},
      {y:88.9,name:'Nashua Country Club'},
      {y:88.9,name:'Hilaman Park Golf Course'},
      {y:89.4,name:'Biltmore Golf Course'},
      {y:89.4,name:'Binks Forest Golf Club'},
      {y:89.4,name:'Binks Forest Golf Club'},
      {y:89.4,name:'Blackhawk Country Club | The Falls'},
      {y:89.4,name:'Blackhawk Country Club | The Falls'},
      {y:89.0,name:'Pembroke Country Club'},{y:89.0,name:'The Greens At North Hills Country Club'},
      {y:89.0,name:'Havana Country Club | Kilamanjaro/Kenya'},
      {y:89.1,name:'Biltmore Golf Course'},
      {y:89.1,name:'Biltmore Golf Course'},
      {y:89.1,name:'Challenge At Santa Rita'},
      {y:89.3,name:'Lake Chabot Golf Course | Lake Chabot'},
      {y:89.4,name:'Hillcrest Golf & Country Club | Championship'},
      {y:89.6,name:'Hillcrest Golf & Country Club | Championship'},{y:89.8,name:'Hillcrest Golf & Country Club | Championship'},
      {y:89.8,name:'Hillcrest Golf & Country Club | Championship'},
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: *Relevent code* please !

Comment: Sorry, coded added. First question I've ever asked.

Comment: Probably not what you want. But you could create a 3rd series by splitting the one in half where the green is one series and the other set are another series. The legend is really only for series and it is working as designed. You may also try and put annotations on the chart itself for the green items.

Comment: Please share the solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just added an empty series with the properties needed (name and color) and it worked. Just in case you find yourself in this scenario.

Comment: It is better to have the empty series' type as 'line' so that it won't affect your main series if it is something like column or bar.

Comment: Above comment is very useful. But one addition to that is use chart type as area if you want legend symbol to be shown as square by default. Having type as line shows the legend symbol as strikeout

Comment: Is there any better way of doing it ?