# Adding an empty series changes axis minimum value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have followed the idea in [How to add an item to Highcharts legend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12185896/how-to-add-an-item-to-highcharts-legend) to add an extra legend entry in my chart.

However the problem is that when I do this, the minimum axis is set to 0 instead of the default highcharts value.

This is what I've added to my series:

```
 {
  "type": "area",
  "name": "Areas with different color",
  "color": "#ee2c34",
  "showInLegend": true,
  "marker": {
    "lineColor": "#8eb79d"
  }
}
```

There's no data points in this series (because I just need the a red legend entry with that title.

Chart without empty series: [image]

However as you can see in https://jsfiddle.net/yuoox653/ the y axis is drawn from 0 instead of the minimum value it would have been drawn without the empty series.

Chart with empty series: [image]

Is there a way to force highcharts to not take empty series into account when calculating minimum and maximum axis values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `type: area` for the extra series and it should be good.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prerak6962/yuoox653/2/)

Comment: I do believe I'm an idiot. Apparently an area chart shades the area between 0 and the given value so highcharts sets 0 to be the minimum. I didn't remove the type but set it to `arearange` instead and it's working fine as well.  I will accept as soon as I'm able.

Comment: It's almost end of the day, so it can happen.. ;)

Comment: There is a special property that lets you enable/disable showing values from 0 and it is called softThreshold (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.softThreshold). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/ys1L92qd/.